# Automatically remove related models on removing selected model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Lesson` model with below fields :

```
lesson_id
title
start_date
end_date
```

And a `Content` model that have these fields :

```
content_id
lesson_id
contentable_id
contentable_type
order
```

A **OneToMany** relationship is between `Lesson` and `Content`.

In addition, I have two another models named `Unit` with these fields :

```
unit_id
title
time
```

And `Test` by these :

```
test_id
title
description
```

Content `contentable_type` and `contentable_id` attributes holds unit (or test) data related to a specific Lesson.

For example in `contentable_type` field of Content can insert only **App\Unit** or **App\Test** string and `contentable_id` holds ID of that Unit or Test.

(Be careful that Content Model is not to create a morph relations between these tables and I created it beacause I want to give Ordering capability to units and test of a Lesson)

Now, Suppose I want to delete a specific Content and related Units (or Tests).

Deleting Content model instance is easy, but to remove related Unit (or Test), I must fetch appropriate model name from `contentable_type` and it's ID then select and delete it.

For that I wrote this :

```
public function destroy ($course_id, $lesson_id, $content_id)
{
    $content   = Content::findOrFail($content_id);
    $modelName = $content->contentable_type;

    $modelName::find($content->contentable_id)->delete();
    $content->delete();
}
```

Despite working properly ,But I think that is not convenient. 
I search for a way that when delete a Content model , this automatically found related model and remove it too.

What is best and Proper solution?

Comment: You can do add a foreign key constraint and add onDelete cascade in migrations, so the delete will be held automatically on database level.  Read more here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Sice related model name Kept in `contentable_type` field as a string I can not use foreign key benefits. if can in this case guide me.

Comment: sorry, my bad, did not notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I just do these changes :

```
public function destroy ($course_id, $lesson_id, $content_id)
        {
            $content   = Content::findOrFail($content_id);
            $content->delete();
        }
```

And in the Content Model :

```
public static function boot()
        {
            static::deleting(function ($content) {

                $modelName = $content->contentable_type;
                $modelName::find($content->contentable_id)->delete();
            });
        }
```

This works fine.
But do this best and Most correct solution?